# embed youtube video in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, google-tag-manager

I track embed youtube videos in google analytics. I found out that without www in the url video is not tracked. For example, [2 urls that differ only with www](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7CZZ.png). [And results are in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBh3I.png). And my question is have I always use www?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is make sure that when a video is first loaded, the page loads the YouTube API library:

script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"

If your site does lazy-load or otherwise dynamically load videos (e.g. if it’s a single-page app), make sure that the library above is loaded before the first video is added to the site.

Comment: I have already included this script. Without it nothing is tracked.